# Python function for loops outside with generator

Tags: python, for-loop, generator

The function below always make my system crash because it takes a high amount of computing power. Is there a way to replace the for loops inside the function or put them outside in combination with a generator or something?!

At best I need an fitting example.

```
def compute_mean_psd_csd(x, n_epochs, nfft, sfreq):
    '''Computes mean of PSD and CSD for signals.'''

    Rxy = np.zeros((n_epochs, channels, channels, n_freqs), dtype=complex)


    Rxx = np.zeros((n_epochs, channels, channels, n_freqs))
    Ryy = np.zeros((n_epochs, channels, channels, n_freqs))
    for i in xrange(0, n_epochs):
        print('computing connectivity for epoch %s'%(i+1))
        for j in xrange(0, channels):
            for k in xrange(0, channels):
                Rxy[i,j,k], freqs = mlab.csd(x[i,j], x[i,k], NFFT=nfft, Fs=sfreq)
                Rxx[i,j,k], _____ = mlab.psd(x[i,j], NFFT=nfft, Fs=sfreq)
                Ryy[i,j,k], _____ = mlab.psd(x[i,k], NFFT=nfft, Fs=sfreq)

    Rxy_mean = np.mean(Rxy, axis=0)
    Rxx_mean = np.mean(Rxx, axis=0)
    Ryy_mean = np.mean(Ryy, axis=0)

    return freqs, Rxy, Rxy_mean, np.real(Rxx_mean), np.real(Ryy_mean)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python improving function speed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31673715/python-improving-function-speed)

Comment: You asked the same question yesterday?

Comment: Is this a question or a statement ?! I posted an similar one, yes. This time I am actually asking for an solution with generators.

Comment: Have you implemented the suggestion given to you on the previous question? Why do you think generators will help, particularly?

Comment: I did implemented the suggestion and it ran faster yes but for a script running for 17min a reduction of 3 seconds isn't that satisfying.

Comment: If you have an idea for how to optimize your code with generators (sounds interesting!), please explain and show us what you tried so far.

Also, I try to think of this site in terms of asking good questions, not asking for solutions. The best answers are often unexpected, so if you already decided what kind of answer you want you might miss something interesting.

Comment: You are totally right. The problem here is I never worked with generators before, I was suggested to do so, but I don't understand them well.

Comment: Generators are basically just sequences that are generated on demand. When you ask for the next value in the sequence, it will be calculated by the generator. This can be a good way to save memory since not all elements of the sequence will be generated at once. In terms of optimizing for speed, I'm not sure generators are that helpful in general. Maybe [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) or memoization (like suggested) are better starts. Can you update your previous question with the caching?

Comment: Thank you all guys, I found a nice and easy way to reduce my 17 minutes running time to just 30seconds. It's no complex solution. My script is based on many function doing parts of my calculation and all did 120 cycles of calculation. Therefore 17minutes. I set the cycles to 1 and let all the functions run 120 times. Very easy and efficient. Like the Zen of Python dictates.

Answer (score 1):

May you should think about parallelizing your loop. If you know the length of channels or n_epochs, you can use more cores and with this module do this.

https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html

Here you can see a simple example of this:

```
>>> from math import sqrt
>>> from joblib import Parallel, delayed
>>> Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(sqrt)(i ** 2) for i in range(10))
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
```

Comment: Nice idea, thank you. But I am obligated to use Editor - Canopy, thus joblib is no option, because I will not subscribe.